# How does one present the features and functionality of an app to a new user

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-behavior

Example: Financial applications require a lot of information before generating reports. What are some good ways to demonstrate the features to users when app hasn't yet been populated with data?

I thought of two ways:
- Videos showing on the application in use
- Allow the user to enter a demo account

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand the question. Are you asking how to convince new users to utilize the application?

Comment: Yes. I'm asking how to prove to the new user what the app can do without asking much information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution is to provide sample data for each of the features in your dashboard. Clearly label that one is providing sample data (example put a "SAMPLE" overlay over the chart/graph). Don't forget to put clear call-to-actions. Example: "Import your data over here."

You can use videos but that's probably not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

When you have complex features that require lots of data to work, consider providing sets of sample data that can be used to demonstrate each  individual feature. You can let the users play around with their own copy of the sample data to get a feel for how they might use these reports.